# Where to place css file for perl cgi script?

Tags: css, apache, perl, cgi

I am currently using `Apache Server` to run my script with the `URL`:

```
http://MY_IP/cgi-bin/example.cgi/
```

which works fine.

However, I'm not sure where to put my `.css` file. I read that it doesn't belong in the `cgi-bin` directory.

This is what I have in my `000-default.conf` file.

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">


AllowOverride None


Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch


Order allow,deny


Allow from all


</Directory>
```

I have tried placing it in here and used:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/var/www/html/login.css"/>
```

but to no avail.

Could someone please help me out with this?

Thank you.

Comment: The href value should be a relative or absolute URL, not a pathname on the server (it is evaluated within the browser).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you put it in the right place. It's just the `href` that you've got wrong.

Your Apache config contains this line

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

This means the the root of your web site is at `/var/www/html`. So a URL that looks at the root of your web site will translate to a file in that directory.

The `href` attribute is a URL, not a file path. Therefore, if you put your `login.css` in this directory, then the correct link would be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/login.css" />
```

But many people would put their CSS files in a subdirectory called `/css/` (which maps to `/var/www/html/css` on your filesystem). If you do that, then the correct link becomes.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/login.css" />
```

Comment: @BrianWiley: It should work in exactly the same way on any operating system (but the directory that's mapped to `DocumentRoot` might well differ).

Answer (score 3):

Although it is always a matter of personal preference, a lot of people create directories under their root directory for javascript, css, images, etc. -- so any static pages would be in `/var/www/html`, and assets are in subdirectories, such as `/var/www/html/css`, `/var/www/html/javascript`, `/var/www/html/images`, and so on.

In your static html pages (in `/var/www/html`), you can reference these using relative links, e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`, `<script src="javascript/my-script.js">` or absolute links, e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://MY_IP/css/style.css">`. For pages on your server but not in `/var/www/html`, using `/css/style.css` is the appropriate form of the relative link, as `/` is equivalent to the local directory `/var/www/html` (that is what setting `DocumentRoot` in Apache does), so `/css` accesses the local directory `/var/www/html/css`.

You can also use the `<base>` tag in the page head to set a base href for all your relative links:

```
<base href="http://MY_IP">
```

Then any relative links (e.g. `href="css/style.css"`) will automatically be interpreted as (e.g.) `http://MY_IP/css/style.css`.